# jqgrid load array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, jqgrid

I have a set of data like the following example and i would like to load it into the grid. However, i'm not sure how since the data doesn't have an name.

```
[[48803,"DSK1","","02200220","OPEN"],[48769,"APPR","","77733337","ENTERED"]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is just use the following [localReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#array_data)

```
localReader: {
    repeatitems: true,
    cell: "",
    id: 0
}
```

I made for you [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LoadArrayData.htm) which shows live how it works.

**UPDATED**: How I could find out the reality is not so good as [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#array_data). The usage of [localReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#array_data) could help you to fill the grid contain with data from `data` parameter with the custom structure, but another parts of jqGrid: **local sorting and searching don't work correct** with this structure of  `data` parameter. I interpret it as a bug. As a pragmatical solution I would recommend you to convert your custom data to array of named objects like

```
[{id:48803,col2:"DSK1",col3:"",col4:"02200220",col5:"OPEN"},
 {id:48769,col2:"APPR",col3:"",col4:"77733337",col5:"ENTERED"}]
```

with the names corresponds to the column names in the `colModel`. If you will use `data` parameter in the form, everything will work perfect in jqGrid.

**UPDATED 2**: Look at the source of [the fixed example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LoadArrayData1.htm) and it will be clear what I mean. In your case conversion of the data can be about the following

```
var myNewData = [];
for (var i=0,l=mydata.length; i<l; i++) {
    var d = mydata[i];
    myNewData.push({id:d[0],col2:d[1],col3:d[2],col4:d[3],col5:d[4]});
}
```

The solution is not so elegant like with `localReader`, but it work without any restrictions.

Comment: @CKeven: I found out some problems in the original solution and appended my answer with additional fixed demo example.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not very familiar with jqgrid, but you could simply assign your data to an associative array and then load it.

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/QWcrT/